# Cordova File Transfer Not Uploading Video To Server Over HTTPS

Tags: cordova, https, file-transfer

I have subdomain installed on different cPanel and has SSL installed too.
I have set .htaccess to redirect to https://sub.domain.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.domain.com
```

Im trying to upload video with [Cordova File Transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) from android to my HTTPS subdomain with php :

```
$tmp_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
exec("ffmpeg -i $tmp_path -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -crf 22 -acodec copy /home/user/public_html/video/$name 2>&1");
```

The problem is upload was success but the video not uploaded to server,
when I tried to empty the .htaccess and upload it again but with HTTP it worked. why is that?